# UI snaps on change of state useRef

Tags: css, reactjs

Is there a reason for `useRef` hook to not get updated on time, im using it for setting state and change css property with emotionjs

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that changing the value of useRef does not initiate a re-render of the state. If you want a re-render, use useState.

https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState

Please share your code for more specific responses. You can still edit your original post.